# Simple JavaScript/jQuery tic tac toe game

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm teaching myself JavaScript/jQuery and was trying to follow [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ThPEH/246/) example to make a simple tic tac toe game. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/a4d2p1jt/) is the link to my version. I left out parts that I couldn't understand, but I seem to have everything working except for switching between X's and O's. Am I missing something obvious as usual? The ternary operator in the last `else` of the `set` function should make the switch.

```
Why do jsfiddle links need to be accompanied by code...?
```

Comment: What if jsfiddle.net website goes down in the future and your question has no code? Your question is not helpful to others anymore.

Comment: If you are learning JS it is easier to start with basic stuff an learn the basics very thorough. Also learn to use your console since errors are silent in JS

Comment: Well, errors are not always silent, but malpractice definitely is silent.
"use strict" should be one's bread and butter when dealing with js.

Comment: Please don't edit meta questions into your initial question. Remember, that what we're doing here is not just answering your question, but creating a public record for anyone else that ever googles a similar problem. That's why its better to ask about the specific error in the title. For that reason we also want code inside the SO question, so years down the line people can still understand what you're talking about. In fact, StackOverflow has a feature which will allow you to embed jsfiddle-like code in the question.

Comment: I see. I will include code as well as links in the future. Could someone explain to me or perhaps link me to somewhere I can learn about the console and/or console.log? I tried Googling it when I was reading through my example, but couldn't understand what it was for. Sorry. I usually try to make specific questions, but I had no idea what was wrong this time.

Comment: Search for "devtools". On Chrome it's ctrl+shift+j or Menu>MoreTools>Javascript tools. On internet explorer it's F12. On Firefox it's...I have no idea anymore. [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console.log) is simply a ubiquitous way of logging things to the console panel of devtools.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to define

```
SIZE=3
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a4d2p1jt/2/

Here you go ;)

A good tip for you while you learn javascript:

```
"use strict";
```

at the start of your code will keep you away from these mistakes: you will need to reference all your variable before using them. Very useful for beginners mistakes like this. Keep going !

Comment: Yup, @Chiharu always check the console. As a matter of fact, always have it open while coding. Its very useful not only for seeing error messages, but also for debugging and playing around with things.

Comment: I didn't get an error message. Did you ?

Comment: yup, open the dev console and start placing Xs

Comment: @V.Roudge Yup console says: SIZE is not defined

Comment: Didn't even open devtools. Just added "use strict" at the start. My mistake!

Comment: Then my initial comment goes for you as well :P

Comment: My face when I've been developping for years and I didn't open my console at first. It's been a long day. :D

Comment: I was unaware of `"use strict";` and did not understand the use of `console.log` in the example. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Don't forget to close the question for future users. btw, console.log & use strict are going to be your friends for a long time if you ever work in js